# ServiceStack.Redis - is sharding supported in sentinel mode?

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack.redis

I'd like to achieve the following high availability setup:

- 2 master nodes (acting as shards of one logical data set with client
  keyhashing)
- 2 slaves (one for each master)
- 6 sentinels (3 for each pair of master/slave)

Now, I know that ServiceStack.Redis provides api for connecting to redis via sentinels:

```
new RedisSentinel(sentinelHosts, masterName: "mymaster").Start().
```

I'm also familiar with a `ShardedRedisClientManager` which calculates hash key and returns corresponding connection pool.

But how can I combine them together, so that my input will be a list of sentinels (on init) and a key for requesting actual data ? Is there a built in support for sharding in sentinels mode ?

Answer (score 2):

I will answer my own question for future googlers.
We found only partial support of sharding in ServiceStack and ended up with this code:

1. `new
   ConsistentHash<RedisSentinelClientManagerWrapper>(clientManagers);`

   - where RedisSentinelClientManagerWrapper is our own class which holds
     instance of sentinel client manager and implements GetHashCode()
   - clientManagers is a list of all those
     sentinel manager wrappers (we have only 2 according to requirements).
2. When application starts, we initialize all client managers and create
   a single instance of ConsistentHash
3. When we need to get/set some
   data in redis, we retrieve redis client from consistent hash in this
   way:

   ```
      var clientManager = consistentHash.GetTarget(key).ClientsManager;
      var client = clientManager.GetClient();
   ```